# Calculating all distances between one point and a group of points efficiently in R

Tags: r, performance, distance

First of all, I am new to R (I started yesterday).

I have two groups of points, `data` and `centers`, the first one of size `n` and the second of size `K` (for instance, `n = 3823` and `K = 10`), and for each `i` in the first set, I need to find `j` in the second with the minimum distance.

My idea is simple: for each `i`, let `dist[j]` be the distance between `i` and `j`, I only need to use `which.min(dist)` to find what I am looking for.

Each point is an array of `64` doubles, so

```
> dim(data)
[1] 3823   64
> dim(centers)
[1] 10 64
```

I have tried with

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:K) {
    d[j] <- sqrt(sum((centers[j,] - data[i,])^2))
  }
  S[i] <- which.min(d)
}
```

which is extremely slow (with `n = 200`, it takes more than 40s!!). The fastest solution that I wrote is

```
distance <- function(point, group) {
  return(dist(t(array(c(point, t(group)), dim=c(ncol(group), 1+nrow(group)))))[1:nrow(group)])
}

for (i in 1:n) {
  d <- distance(data[i,], centers)
  which.min(d)
}
```

Even if it does a lot of computation that I don't use (because `dist(m)` computes the distance between all rows of `m`), it is way more faster than the other one (can anyone explain why?), but it is not fast enough for what I need, because it will not be used only once. And also, the `distance` code is very ugly. I tried to replace it with

```
distance <- function(point, group) {
  return (dist(rbind(point,group))[1:nrow(group)])
}
```

but this seems to be twice slower. I also tried to use `dist` for each pair, but it is also slower.

I don't know what to do now. It seems like I am doing something very wrong. Any idea on how to do this more efficiently?

ps: I need this to implement k-means by hand (and I need to do it, it is part of an assignment). I believe I will only need Euclidian distance, but I am not yet sure, so I will prefer to have some code where the distance computation can be replaced easily. `stats::kmeans` do all computation in less than one second.

Comment: People 'round here kind-a-don't-like-doing assignments... so try to focus on a specific problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than iterating across data points, you can just condense that to a matrix operation, meaning you only have to iterate across `K`.

```
# Generate some fake data.
n <- 3823
K <- 10
d <- 64
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * d), ncol = n)
centers <- matrix(rnorm(K * d), ncol = K)

system.time(
  dists <- apply(centers, 2, function(center) {
    colSums((x - center)^2)
})
)
```

Runs in:

```
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      0.100       0.008       0.108
```

on my laptop.

Comment: +1 beats my way to calculate dists matrix. This is nice trick with auto-replication vector added or subtracted from matrix.

Comment: I am trying to use your solution, but your matrix are transposed. Is there a way to subtract lines like you did with columns?

Comment: I tried the subtraction with lines using apply but it was not so fast as your solution. I am now transposing the matrix and using your code and it is really fast! Many thanks!!! And also, thank you for your complete answer with a small example and the use of system.time. Merci beaucoup :)

Answer (score 4):

rdist() is a R function from {fields} package which is able to calculate distances between two sets of points in matrix format quickly.

https://www.image.ucar.edu/~nychka/Fields/Help/rdist.html

Usage :

```
library(fields)
#generating fake data
n <- 5
m <- 10
d <- 3

x <- matrix(rnorm(n * d), ncol = d)
y <- matrix(rnorm(m * d), ncol = d)

rdist(x, y)
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
 [1,] 1.512383 3.053084 3.1420322 4.942360 3.345619
 [2,] 3.531150 4.593120 1.9895867 4.212358 2.868283
 [3,] 1.925701 2.217248 2.4232672 4.529040 2.243467
 [4,] 2.751179 2.260113 2.2469334 3.674180 1.701388
 [5,] 3.303224 3.888610 0.5091929 4.563767 1.661411
 [6,] 3.188290 3.304657 3.6668867 3.599771 3.453358
 [7,] 2.891969 2.823296 1.6926825 4.845681 1.544732
 [8,] 2.987394 1.553104 2.8849988 4.683407 2.000689
 [9,] 3.199353 2.822421 1.5221291 4.414465 1.078257
[10,] 2.492993 2.994359 3.3573190 6.498129 3.337441
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look into the `apply` functions.

For instance, this code

```
for (j in 1:K)
    {
    d[j] <- sqrt(sum((centers[j,] - data[i,])^2))
    }
```

Can easily be substituted by something like

```
dt <- data[i,]
d <- apply(centers, 1, function(x){ sqrt(sum(x-dt)^2)})
```

You can definitely optimise it more but you get the point I hope

Comment: Thanks... It is a faster than the first code that I wrote but not even close to the strange one using `distance`.

Comment: @dbarbosa: well, apparently the `stats::kmeans` package uses compiled code that is obviously faster. Just type `kmeans` and you'll see the source code for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`dist` works fast because is't vectorized and call internal C functions.
You code in loop could be vectorized in many ways.

For example to compute distance between `data` and `centers` you could use `outer`:

```
diff_ij <- function(i,j) sqrt(rowSums((data[i,]-centers[j,])^2))
X <- outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(K), diff_ij)
```

This gives you `n x K` matrix of distances. And should be way faster than loop.

Then you could use `max.col` to find maximum in each row (see help, there are some nuances when are many maximums). `X` must be negate cause we search for minimum.

```
CL <- max.col(-X)
```

To be efficient in R you should vectorized as possible. Loops could be in many cases replaced by vectorized substitute. Check help for `rowSums` (which describe also `rowMeans`, `colSums`, `rowSums`), `pmax`, `cumsum`. You could search SO, e.g. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+avoid+loop (copy&paste this link, I don't how to make it clickable) for some examples.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use your code but it is not working. I tried to use it with the same code that @Jonathan Chang wrote, adding: `system.time(outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(K), function(i,j) sqrt(rowSums((x[,i]-centers[,j])^2))))`, but I am getting this error:

`Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : dims [product 38230] do not match the length of object [64]`

Do you see what is wrong?

Comment: Actually I was not understanding `outer` (I thought it was calling the function once for each pair). Now I am understanding it, thank you, it can be useful! And also, thanks for telling about `max.col`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
# data is a matrix where each row is a point
# point is a vector of values
euc.dist <- function(data, point) {
  apply(data, 1, function (row) sqrt(sum((point - row) ^ 2)))
}
```

You can try it, like:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5)
euc.dist(x, x[1,])
```