# Computing sparse pairwise distance matrix in R

Tags: r, distance, sparse-matrix, knn

I have a `NxM` matrix and I want to compute the `NxN` matrix of Euclidean distances between the `M` points.  In my problem, `N` is about 100,000.  As I plan to use this matrix for a k-nearest neighbor algorithm, I only need to keep the `k` smallest distances, so the resulting `NxN` matrix is very sparse.  This is in contrast to what comes out of `dist()`, for example, which would result in a dense matrix (and probably storage problems for my size `N`).

The packages for kNN that I've found so far (`knnflex`, `kknn`, etc) all appear to use dense matrices.  Also, the `Matrix` package does not offer a pairwise distance function.

Closer to my goal, I see that the `spam` package has a `nearest.dist()` function that allows one to only consider distances less than some threshold, `delta`.  In my case, however, a particular value of `delta` may produce too many distances (so that I have to store the `NxN` matrix densely) or too few distances (so that I can't use kNN).

I have seen previous discussion on trying to perform [k-means clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039646/k-means-clustering-in-r-on-very-large-sparse-matrix) using the `bigmemory/biganalytics` packages, but it doesn't seem like I can leverage these methods in this case.

Does anybody know a function/implementation that will compute a distance matrix in a sparse fashion in R?  My (dreaded) backup plan is to have two `for` loops and save results in a `Matrix` object.

Comment: Just making sure... You know about `dist` http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dist.html, right?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about why dist() is not adequate for my situation.  It results in a dense matrix and it's a bit annoying to store the NxN matrix.

Comment: You should probably either accept one of the answers here that you think actually answers the question (your own if you think it fits best), or edit your question to clarify why they do not.

Comment: "a bit annoying" is an understatement -- if N is 100,000, that's a 480Gb matrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, we can't have you resorting to for-loops, now can we :)

There is of course the question of how to represent the sparse matrix. A simple way is to have it only contain the indices of the points that are closest (and recalculate as needed). But in the solution below, I put both distance ('d1' etc) and index ('i1' etc) in a single matrix:

```
sparseDist <- function(m, k) {
    m <- t(m)
    n <- ncol(m)
    d <- vapply( seq_len(n-1L), function(i) { 
        d<-colSums((m[, seq(i+1L, n), drop=FALSE]-m[,i])^2)
        o<-sort.list(d, na.last=NA, method='quick')[seq_len(k)]
        c(sqrt(d[o]), o+i) 
        }, numeric(2*k)
    )
    dimnames(d) <- list(c(paste('d', seq_len(k), sep=''),
        paste('i', seq_len(k), sep='')), colnames(m)[-n])
    d
}
```

Trying it out on 9 2d-points:

```
> m <- matrix(c(0,0, 1.1,0, 2,0, 0,1.2, 1.1,1.2, 2,1.2, 0,2, 1.1,2, 2,2),
              9, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(letters[1:9], letters[24:25]))
> print(dist(m), digits=2)
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
b 1.1                            
c 2.0 0.9                        
d 1.2 1.6 2.3                    
e 1.6 1.2 1.5 1.1                
f 2.3 1.5 1.2 2.0 0.9            
g 2.0 2.3 2.8 0.8 1.4 2.2        
h 2.3 2.0 2.2 1.4 0.8 1.2 1.1    
i 2.8 2.2 2.0 2.2 1.2 0.8 2.0 0.9
> print(sparseDist(m, 3), digits=2)
     a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
d1 1.1 0.9 1.2 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.1 0.9
d2 1.2 1.2 1.5 1.1 0.9 1.2 2.0  NA
d3 1.6 1.5 2.0 1.4 1.2 2.2  NA  NA
i1 2.0 3.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 8.0 9.0
i2 4.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 9.0  NA
i3 5.0 6.0 9.0 8.0 9.0 7.0  NA  NA
```

And trying it on a larger problem (10k points). Still, on 100k points and more dimensions it will take a long time (like 15-30 minutes).

```
n<-1e4; m<-3; m=matrix(runif(n*m), n)
system.time( d <- sparseDist(m, 3) ) # 9 seconds on my machine...
```

P.S. Just noted that you posted an answer as I was writing this: the solution here is roughly twice as fast because it doesn't calculate the same distance twice (the distance between points 1 and 13 is the same as between points 13 and 1).

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I agree it's about twice as fast.  However, for my application (kNN) I think having only the upper triangle of the distance matrix is actually slightly inconvenient.  I think I may stick with a parallelized version of the code I submitted.  Thanks again though!

Answer (score 3):

For now I am using the following, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029639/calculating-all-distances-between-one-point-and-a-group-of-points-efficiently-in).  The output is a `n x k` matrix where element `(i,k)` is the index of the data point that is the `k`th closest to `i`.

```
n <- 10
d <- 3
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * d), ncol = n)

min.k.dists <- function(x,k=5) {
  apply(x,2,function(r) {
    b <- colSums((x - r)^2)
    o <- order(b)
    o[1:k]
  })
}

min.k.dists(x)  # first row should be 1:ncol(x); these points have distance 0
dist(t(x))      # can check answer against this
```

If one is worried about how ties are handled and whatnot, perhaps `rank()` should be incorporated.

The above code seems somewhat fast, but I'm sure it could be improved (though I don't have time to go the `C` or `fortran` route).  So I'm still open to fast and sparse implementations of the above.

Below I include a parallelized version that I ended up using:

```
min.k.dists <- function(x,k=5,cores=1) {
  require(multicore)
  xx <- as.list(as.data.frame(x))
  names(xx) <- c()
  m <- mclapply(xx,function(r) {
    b <- colSums((x - r)^2)
    o <- order(b)
    o[1:k]
  },mc.cores=cores)
  t(do.call(rbind,m))
}
```

Comment: You need to do dist(t(x)) to get a comparable answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the logic of your min.k.dist function and return duplicate distances, you might want to consider modifying it a bit. It seems pointless to return the first line with 0 distance, right? ...and by incorporating some of the tricks in my other answer, you can speed up your version by some 30%:

```
min.k.dists2 <- function(x, k=4L) {
  k <- max(2L, k + 1L)
  apply(x, 2, function(r) {
    sort.list(colSums((x - r)^2), na.last=NA, method='quick')[2:k]
  })
}

> n<-1e4; m<-3; m=matrix(runif(n*m), n)
> system.time(d <- min.k.dists(t(m), 4)) #To get 3 nearest neighbours and itself
   user  system elapsed 
  17.26    0.00   17.30 
> system.time(d <- min.k.dists2(t(m), 3)) #To get 3 nearest neighbours
   user  system elapsed 
   12.7     0.0    12.7
```